# Can't parse json string retrieved from server in android but can parse as string defined in android

Tags: android, json

I'm getting this error while trying to create a `JSONObject` in android

`org.json.JSONException: Value {"0" : [{"original" : "car", "translation" : "araba"}]}` of type `java.lang.String` cannot be converted to `JSONObject`

I get the above error if I use the string returned from the server using `HttpClient`.

If I take the same string above and define a static string and parse that it's fine. Is there some decoding or encoding issue that I have to account for when using `HttpClient` to retrieve the `JSON`?

I'm building the `JSON` String manually in c# as a test and returning it

```
return "{\"0\" : [{\"original\" : \"car\", \"translation\" : \"araba\"}]}";
```

here is the code

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        String s = "http://10.0.2.2:63200/OnlineArabic/api/datasen";
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(s);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReaderinstream , "UTF-8"),8 );
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

         String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


        String result= convertStreamToString(instream);             
    String jsonString = sb.toString();
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Any idea?

Here is the log:

```
12-01 13:48:08.156: W/System.err(22947): org.json.JSONException: Value {&quot;0&quot; : [{&quot;original&quot; : &quot;car&quot;, &quot;translation&quot; : &quot;araba&quot;}]} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-01 13:48:08.160: W/System.err(22947):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
12-01 13:48:08.160: W/System.err(22947):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
12-01 13:48:08.160: W/System.err(22947):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
12-01 13:48:08.170: W/System.err(22947):    at com.ls.audioplayer.MainActivity.call(MainActivity.java:137)
12-01 13:48:08.170: W/System.err(22947):    at com.ls.audioplayer.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:294)
12-01 13:48:08.180: W/System.err(22947):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-01 13:48:08.180: W/System.err(22947):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-01 13:48:08.190: W/System.err(22947):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-01 13:48:08.190: W/System.err(22947):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-01 13:48:08.221: W/System.err(22947):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-01 13:48:08.221: W/System.err(22947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-01 13:48:08.221: W/System.err(22947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 13:48:08.231: W/System.err(22947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-01 13:48:08.231: W/System.err(22947):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-01 13:48:08.240: W/System.err(22947):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-01 13:48:08.240: W/System.err(22947):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: 1. Logs please
2. Try a online json formatter/convertor to check your json

Comment: Where is your Android code for creating the JSONObject?

Comment: I've added the code that creates the JSONObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the server is sending UTF-8 encoded data. Also see that there are no new line characters  in the beginning/end.

Eclipse's logcat tool will help you find these special characters. Logcat on command line sometimes doesnt render the special characters.

Comment: The server had extra data so I cleared the stream and sent back only the json

Answer (score 0):

My only though is that you are somehow destroying the string as it comes in with your httpget code, I would recommend you use a library for http requests such as [EasyHttpClient](https://github.com/uscheller/EasyHttpClient/blob/master/src/EasyHttpClient.java) , just create that class in your project and then instead of all that code you have do

```
EasyHttpClient client = new EasyHttpClient();
String jsonString = client.get("http://10.0.2.2:63200/OnlineArabic/api/datasen");
```

Then see if you can put that in an object. I cant test that code unfortunately I only have android 4.2 installed here.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReaderinstream , "UTF-8"),8 );

change this to

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream , "UTF-8"),8 );